# The "to be" part in a "It seems ____" phrase

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, construction

Is it acceptable to drop that 'to be' or 'to have been' parts when using the verb 'seem' **before a noun/noun phrase**?

> The author — as it **seems** his custom  — does not specify the age of his characters.

Comment: Yep, perfectly fine, common, and idiomatic.

Comment: **-as seems his custom-** sounds more natural.